# How to select a element with a Javascript library

Tags: javascript

I am working on a javascript [library](https://github.com/CodeApprentice/TechX), The library syntax will go as follows: `tex(selector).function(specifier)`. Here is what I have so far:

```
(function(){
    var tex = function(selector,context){
                //code

    },
    tex.prototype = {
         show: function () {
             this.style.display = "inherit";
             return this
         }
    };
    window.tex = tex
})();
```

The problem I am having is how do I set `this` to the element. Does anyone know how I can do that the jQuery way?

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Look at the jQuery source and see how it does it.

Comment: @Barmar I have but it is hard for me to understand. That is why I am asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try :

```
if (document.querySelectorAll(selector==null || undefined) {
//nothing there

} else {
tex = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that sets the value of itself, jQuery somehow sets this to the element. You still get an upvote for trying.

Comment: According to the spec, this returns a node list of the marched elements, not set the values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll  I updated my answer to use querySelectorAll to not just return the first element, but all found